# Foursquare API usage: /venue/stats

Tags: java, foursquare

I have couple of doubts regarding the usage and working of /venue/stats Foursquare API.

Q1. I would be using /venue/stats for getting information provided a venue id. So I have registered my app and got the client id and secret values. I went to Foursquare API endpoint and tried using /venue/stats api and I noticed a oauth_token generated automatically by FSQ so is this oauth_token the same token that I am required to use everytime I use this api ? Do I need to do the authentication steps mentioned ?

Q2. Try the api generates a link which has /simulate in the api URL. I assume that this is due to the fact that I am testing the API so FSQ has categorized such api calls as simulate calls. Please confirm my understanding. If this is so then whenever I use the api as mentioned i.e. /v2/venues/venue_id/stats I get an error JSON stating that I am unauthorized to view venue stats. Can you please tell me why ? If this is due to access_token issue then the same issue should have been with simulate call also ?

Hoping to get a reply soon.

Answer (score 1):

Right underneath the API Explorer bar it says "OAuth token automatically added". You do not use this token. I am sure it is either temporary or created using your log in info if you are loggged in while using the API Explorer. You will still have to use the authentication process to get a valid access token. However, you can save this access token and use it again skipping the Auth process. An access token serves as a key unique to a user and app. Read more about it here: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

The simulate feature is used mostly for API calls that normally would require you to be a manager of the venue. There are certain calls that can not be done unless the app is by a user that is the manager or unless you make the call using an access token of a manager.